# ¿Como aplicar transformaciones CSS3 a un elemento padre sin afectar los elementos hijos?

Tags: html5, css3

Necesito aplicar una transformación de scale y skew a un div, pero al realizar dicha transformación resulta que también se le aplica a los elementos hijos.

¿Como hago para que los elementos hijos omitan esa propiedad?

Comment: Hola Camilo, por favor indica __cómo lo estás haciendo__ y, si es posible, indica cuál es el resultado esperado. Edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente, como ya te han comentado, se podría realizar esto simplemente revirtiendo el valor de la transformación para los elementos hijos. Sin embargo, yo usaría el selector `#padre > *` o `padre *` para indicar que todos los hijos de ese padre, sean el elemento que sean, reviertan dicha propiedad (el primer selector haría referencia a los hijos directos del padre y el segundo a cualquier elemento dentro del padre).

También añadiría un ID si es solamente un elemento el que va a ser transformado o una clase si van a ser varios elementos transformados con las mismas propiedades pero si pones `div` harás referencia a cada uno de los elementos `div` de tu página.

También tendrás que tener en cuenta si tienes elementos `inline` dentro de tu contenedor padre o no, ya que estos no aplicarán ninguna transformación y por tanto no podrán revertir tampoco la transformación del elemento padre. Para que esta transformación sea posible deberás indicar que tus elementos `inline` se comporten como `inline-block` o `block`.

Tomando como referencia el ejemplo de la otra respuesta:

```css
.distorsionado {
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  transform: skew(30deg) scale(1.5);
  max-width:200px;
  margin:50px auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.divHijo{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.distorsionado.not > *{
  transform: skew(-30deg) scale(.66);
}

#padre > *{
  display: block;
  transform: skew(-30deg) scale(.66);
}
```

```html
<h3>Los elementos hijos heredando del padre.</h3>
<div class="distorsionado">
  <p>Distorsionado</p>
  <div class="divHijo">Esto es un div</div>
  <span>Distorsionado</span>
</div>

<h3>Los elementos hijos que son inline-block o block sin herencia.</h3>
<h3>Elementos inline no aplican esta reversión. </h3>
<div class="distorsionado not">
  <p>No Distorsionado</p>
  <div class="divHijo">Esto es un div</div>
  <span>Distorsionado</span>
</div>

<h3>Ninguno de los elemento hijos tiene herencia.</h3>
<h3>Todos son tratados como block.</h3>
<div id="padre" class="distorsionado">
  <p>No Distorsionado</p>
  <div class="divHijo">Esto es un div</div>
  <span>No distorsionado</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Evitar que las propiedades afecten a los elementos hijos no es posible. Usualmente lo que se hace es revertir las propiedades del padre, algo por este estilo:

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  transform: skew(30deg) scale(1.5);
  max-width:200px;
  margin:50px auto;
  text-align:center;
}
div.not p {
  transform: skew(-30deg) scale(.66);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Distorsionado</p>
</div>
<div class="not">
  <p>No Distorsionar</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Tengo una pregunta, que operación hiciste para saber que valor colocar en el scale del elemento con clase not?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez basicamente es un pequeño lio matemático XD.. tras la primera transformación el elemento aumento su tamaño en `.5`  lo que hace que su tamaño original sea 2/3 del actual ... por tanto para revertir el aumento ahora necesito un elemento de 2/3 de tamaño osea `.66`; es un aproximado creo que es la propiedad mas complicada de revertir

Comment: Muchas gracias, problema resuelto ! :D

Comment: Para obtener la *inversa* de una escala, sólo hay que calcular `1 / escala`... Ejemplo: `1 / 1.5 = 0.66667`

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion @Mariano